# How can I install an old version of a ReSharper plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-8.0, resharper-plugins

I'm using ReSharper 8.0 in Visual Studio 2010. ReSharper 8.0 uses a [NuGet-based Extension Manager](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Managing_Extensions.html) for plugin management, which makes it very easy to find and install plugins, but this Extension Manager will only offer up the **latest** version of any given plugin. It also keeps track of plugin updates, and offers to update plugins when a new version is available.

This is where my problem has arisen. A particular plugin I use (`GoToWord`) has been updated, and the latest version (`0.9.3`) appears not to work. I cannot work out any way to roll back to the previous good version (`0.9.1.1`), nor a way to install an older version once I've uninstalled it.

I've tried opening the regular NuGet package manager console (at `Tools | Library Package Manager | Package Manager Console`) and issuing this command:

```
Install-Package resharper.GoToWord -version 0.9.1.1
```

But this fails at the dependency resolution phase, presumably because ReSharper isn't known to the *regular* NuGet:

> ```
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'ReSharper (≥ 8.0)'.
> Install-Package : Unable to resolve dependency 'ReSharper (≥ 8.0)'.
> At line:1 char:16
> + Install-Package <<<<  resharper.GoToWord -version 0.9.1.1
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
> ```

**Does the ReSharper Extension Manager version of NuGet have a console? Or is there some other way to install an old version of a plugin?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, we didn't implement support for installing older versions of a plugin. But you should be able fake it manually, by editing the `packages.config` file in the `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny` folder and adding a line such as:

```
<package id="ReSharper.GoToWord" version="0.9.1.1" />
```

If you restart VS now, and go to the extension manager, you should get prompted that some extensions aren't installed, and clicking the package restore button should download and install the right version.

Have you reported the issue on the project's GitHub page? https://github.com/controlflow/resharper-gotoword/issues

Comment: It's back! I could kiss you! Now I will go and report the issue (I was going to, honest!)

Comment: Hmm. No, I don't think we support restoring packages in the installer. You could try adding the version to the `packages.config` in one of the locations listed in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\plugins\repositories.config`, and then running the installer, either via the add/remove control panel, or ReSharper's Check for Updates in the Help menu. I have no idea if it will work or not (also, the Go To Word plugin definitely doesn't work with ReSharper 10).